# 'One among the team' or 'Part of the team'

Tags: word-choice

I would like to convey that I was one of the person in the organizing committee which successfully organized a corporate event.

> one among the team which successfully organized the event

or

> part of the team which organized the event successfully

Comment: You got the *noun* wrong in your question text (should be plural ***people***, not singular ***person***), but you have actually used the most natural form there - you were ***one of the team** [that did something].*

Comment: It should be *part of the team __who__* because it's a human.

Answer (score 1):

The second is more natural, and is used all the time.

Comment: It also emphasises that you worked as a team, rather than being one of several people who worked separately.